# I'm trying to build a module, but can't mind why it's not working?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

My module called `Test`, and a back-office controller to this is `check`, here is the code

```
class TestCheckModuleAdminController extends ModuleAdminController {

    public function __construct()
    {

        echo "Checked!";

    }

}
```

And when I'm going to `mysite/admin/index.php?controller=check&module=test` I'm getting the message that it doesn't exists, so whats went wrong?

I'm even turned on valid urls for it and it must be like this:

`mysite/admin/module/test/check` but no response to this.

Though if it is a Front Controller like this:

```
class TestCheckModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController {

    public function __construct()
    {

        echo "Checked Front!";

    }

}
```

url for this will be like `mysite/module/test/check` and it's allright.

I guess that it is no rewrite rules for this in `.htaccess`

I tried this...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.test$
RewriteRule ^admin([0-9]{4})/module/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+) module=$1&controller=$2 [L]
```

maybe it's not right, but close to the answer.

**upd 1.**

```
prestashop/modules/mymodule/controllers/admin/check.php
```

and it's source right now:

```
class TestCheckController extends ModuleAdminController {

    public function __construct()
    {   
        echo "Checked!";
    }

}
```

What url I must to use for it?

**upd 2.** Well, I have a new tab in my admin/tabs list. But still can't go a controller on it.

[image: russian panel]

What I can do with this tab btw? Maybe I can put it anywhere on admin menu isn't?

[image: check]

How can get this check controller from a url than?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the name you should just write TestCheckController instead of TestCheckModuleAdminController. I did it recently and it works for me.

You can also extend the Prestashop menubar in the way you won't need to provide a token by yourself:

in you module install method, add the following code:

```
$parentTab = new Tab();
$parentTab->name[$this->context->language->id] = $this->l'('My module Top tab');
$parentTab->class_name = 'TopModuleNav';
$parentTab->id_parent = 0;
$parentTab->module = $this->name;
$parentTab->add();

$adminMenuItem = new Tab();
$adminMenuItem->name[$this->context->language->id] = $this->l'('Admin Menu Item');
$adminMenuItem->class_name = "TestCheck";
$adminMenuItem->module = $this->name;
$adminMenuItem->id_parent = $parentTab->id;
$adminMenuItem->add();
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Well, I have a tab, but each time I've reset my module new tab have been added. Seems the module need a tab-removal mechanism.

Comment: And still can't mind how to get catch a controller by a token url.

Comment: for example if the `class_name = 'Check'` then my controller must be in `mymodule/controllers/admin/check.php` isn't it? And contain a class: `class CheckController extends ModuleAdminController {

 public function __construct()
 {
  echo "Test! Check!";
 }

}` but, thats not working.

Answer (score 1):

At BackOffice your controller is "TestCheckModule"
so you should call it via:

admin/index.php?controller=TestCheckModule&token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

you should provide a proper token as well.

You do not need to provide the module name in the URL.

It's a good practice to prefix the controller with "Admin"